# "Format Exception was Unhandeled" in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

What is wrong here in the code

```
 Dim sReaderList As String
    sReaderList = New System.String(vbNullChar, 1024)
    Dim x As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(sReaderList)
```

When debug it produce "Format Exception was Unhandeled"
and Input string was not in a correct format in vb.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to convert a string filled with non digits to integer... so you're getting the error.
Did you expect something different? Why?

If you want to catch the exception, you could do

```
    Dim sReaderList As String
    sReaderList = New System.String(vbNullChar, 1024)
    Try
        Dim x As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(sReaderList)
    Catch
        ' Manage the error here
    End Try
```

Note, just for example, that if you insert a digit at the beginning of the string, the error disappear.

```
sReaderList = "1" & sReaderList
Dim x As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(sReaderList) ' This works
```

Comment: Thanx,Actually I am new in the vb.net.Can you explain me what the 1024 means.

Comment: @vikky: you're creating a new string filled with 1024 vbNullChar

Answer (score 1):

`Convert.ToInt32` throws a format exception when the given string either contains invalid characters or is an empty string (note that `Nothing` would be ok, but `''` is not).

As mentioned by Marco you have to catch the exception or be sure that the string contains only valid numerical characters (and vbNullChar is not one of those). Also: if the possibility of empty strings arises, you have to manually check for this or again catch the exception.

Answer (score 1):

The error is happening because you are trying to convert something to an integer which cant be converted so it is throwing an exception.

There are two approaches you can use to solve this problem:

1) Wrap it all in a try / catch block

```
 Dim sReaderList As String
  sReaderList = New System.String(vbNullChar, 1024)
  Try
     Dim x As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(sReaderList)
  Catch ex As Exception

  End Try
```

2) use the Tryparse method

```
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim s As String = String.Empty
  Dim result As Boolean

  result = Integer.TryParse(s, i)

    If (result) Then
        'Code here
    End If
```